# Way to disable Intel TurboBoost before boot or during Windows Setup?

Tags: cpu, bios, bsod, intel-core-i7, turbo-boost

I'll try long story short.

I have an Asus TUF504GM laptop with i7 8750H processor.
Recently I was having BSODs, and even couldn't install Windows 10 or any other OS because was always crashing, tried replace RAM, SSD, bios update etc.. nothing worked.

Then one day I've tried to see processor features and disabling to see what happens and voi-la! The turboboost (with freaking loud coil whine sound) was killing the laptop. Disabled it and everything is working perfectly!

But, if I decide to format can't do a windows restore or a fresh new install, because the turboboost comes back, and the way that I'm disabling turboboost is using ThrottleStop software, Quick CPU worked fine too.
The intel XTU don't give the chance to disable TurboBoost.

In the BIOS there isn't an option to disable turboboost :(

So, I was thinking if there's a way, before boot or during a windows setup disable turboboost, because again, it was killing the laptop!

Comment: Chances are that loud coil whine is a sign that your PSU is under too much load or is dying. Turbo boost is going to draw more power and as a result put more strain on the PSU circuitry. You might want to get it looked at by a professional rather than treating symptoms.

Comment: I tried to send this laptop to 3 different "motherboard specialists", nobody solved anything .. everyone condemned the motherboard, last one just said, "this is ain't a hardware issue" ....